# Specify SpotFleet instances to stop instead of terminate in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a SpotFleet via CloudFormation which stops its instances rather than terminating them upon interupt.

`SpotFleetRequestConfigData` as per 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_SpotFleetRequestConfigData.html has an `InstanceInterruptionBehavior` property, but setting it causes CloudFormation to throw `Encountered unsupported property InstanceInterruptionBehavior`.

Given that the same property isn't present on the CloudFormation page for the `SpotFleetRequestConfigData`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html I'm assuming I'm going to have to be patient or am I overlooking something?

Many thanks,

Edit: Despite http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html it doesn't seem to work from the SpotFleet console either.

Edit: Got it to work in the end by manually entering everything in the spot request. It broke when trying to use a launch template which has a shutdown behaviour of 'stop' specified.

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to work from the SpotFleet console either"*  In what sense does it not work?

Comment: Got it to work in the end by manually entering everything in the spot request. It broke for me when trying to use a launch template which has a shutdown behaviour of 'stop' specified. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is only supported through the console or aws cli for ec2 instances. Cloudformation does not support this and a few other arguments, just as you discovered as it is not (yet) a supported option here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html